# is the question about different types of learning off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Almost all teachers I had (piano, theory, singing) had the position:
If you don't want the bread I'm selling you can leave. They were not my private teacher, they were payed by the state and also by me, by the taxes of citizen and my own money too. I was their client.

Could this be an arrogance that you find only among music teachers?

And when someone here was asking "why teachers insist of sheet reading?"  this question was on hold because opinion based ...

[Why do music teachers emphasize reading sheet music and not playing by ear?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/70323/why-do-music-teachers-emphasize-reading-sheet-music-and-not-playing-by-ear/70328#70328)

"closed as primarily opinion-based!" I don't agree:This is not at all a opinion based question. It is absolutely evident that there are different types of learners (and this should not be depending of the teacher.) Therefore a discussion about the methods of teaching should be quite appropriate in this site. Richard has mentioned some important points. This question concerns students as well as teachers.

P.S.

I also emphasize reading - by the way!

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in a comment under that question, it is looking for discussion, which means it is almost certainly off topic. This is not a discussion site. We do not want a discussion around methods of teaching.

It is absolutely an opinion piece - if you try asking teachers what they emphasize you may get different answers, and you will get different reasons as to why they answered that way.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what Doktor Mayhem has said, the original question is not really answerable.

The premise that music teachers in general emphasize reading over playing by ear is at best debatable. Teachers have differing opinions on what should be taught and when, and in particular may emphasize reading at one stage of the process, playing by ear at another stage, and ear training at yet another stage. And as Albrecht Hügli has pointed out both in this Meta question and in comments under the SE Music question being discussed, individual learners may have different needs which a good teacher would take into account.

All of this makes the original question an unanswerable request for discussion, and liable to devolve into opinions (in my opinion). That means that questions of this sort, while not inherently uninteresting, are off-topic at SE Music.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, while I respect any balance of opinion that states that questions that might attract various opinions are off-topic, I'd be happy to see some such questions here - including, perhaps, this one.

There are a large number of SE sites (worldbuilding, parenting, the workplace, IPS) whose main currency is very opinion-based questions and answers, so there doesn't seem to be a major impediment to SE sites working with those kind of questions. Of course there are as many, if not more, sites that like to stick to more objective questions - at the moment it seems that we are one of these.

Comment: anyway - in my opinion! - it would be probably more useful, fruitful and with more benefit for beginners to discuss some (even opinion based) critical questions than to answer again and again elamentary music theory based questions that could be answered by looking up a term in wiki.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli I's personally agree - all that's really needed for these kind of questions to work (in my opinion) is a recognition that when questions do invite opinions, those opinions can be respected even if they are disagreed with...